# Display content on load

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 divs and would like to have the content of the associated div be displayed when dropdown selection is made. I was able to find something pretty close and tried to adjust to do exactly what I needed but I am having no luck. I would like the content of the first div to display on the initial load by default and after that display (replace) whatever selection is made. 
It may not look like I spend a lot of time from the code but what I have right now is pretty messy and I had to pull this out to make it easier to understand what I am trying to do. Please help.

```
<select id="target">
    <option value="content_1" selected="selected">Content All</option>
    <option value="content_2">Content 2</option>
    <option value="content_3">Content 3</option>
    <option value="content_4">Content 4</option>
<select>
<div id="content_1" class="inv">
    Content All
</div>
<div id="content_2" class="inv">
        Content 2
</div>
<div id="content_3" class="inv">
        Content 3
</div>

<div id="content_4" class="inv">
        Content 4
</div>
<script>
    document
        .getElementById('target')
        .addEventListener('change', function() {
            'use strict';
            var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
                target = document.getElementById(this.value);
            if (vis !== null) {
                vis.className = 'inv';
            }
            if (target !== null) {
                target.className = 'vis';
            }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ... `<div id="content_1" class="vis">` ... i mean... if you have no problem hardcoding the first option to be selected, why can't you also hardcode the first div to already have the `vis` class?

Comment: @Irma, please take a moment to format your code

Comment: I think it is formatted better now. I realized that it was not formatted correctly after I clicked Submit. If I hard code the first div, then it only works the first time. It becomes invisible after that. Tried that.

Comment: @Irma works fine for me hardcoding. https://jsfiddle.net/h3p5qbzk/ All i did was swap `inv` for `vis` on the `content_1` div.

Comment: For whatever reason, I am not able to make it work. I will keep looking. It works on load then I pick something else and it stops working after I come back to the default selection.

Comment: I was able to make it work using your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to handle this is to understand that you'll have 4 valid list options to choose from (the first one doesn't count) and an equal number of hidden divs. The div that corresponds to the selected list item is the div to show.

See comments inline:

```js
// Get a reference to the default div
var defaultDiv = document.getElementById("default");

// Get all the hidden <div> elements into an array
var hiddenDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".hidden"));

document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('change', function () {
  // Hide all the divs
  defaultDiv.classList.add("hidden");
  hiddenDivs.forEach(function(div){ div.classList.add("hidden") });
  
  // Show the div that corresponds to the index of the selected list item
  // We subtract 1 from the selected index to account for the first option, 
  // which really isn't a valid selection.
  hiddenDivs[this.selectedIndex -1].classList.remove("hidden");
  
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<select id="target">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Content All</option>
        <option value="content_1">Content 1</option>        
        <option value="content_2">Content 2</option>
        <option value="content_3">Content 3</option>
        <option value="content_4">Content 4</option>
    <select>
    
    <div id="default">Default</div>
    <div class="hidden">Other 1</div> 
    <div class="hidden">Other 2</div>  
    <div class="hidden">Other 3</div>  
    <div class="hidden">Other 4</div>
```

Comment: **A down vote literally less than a second after posting. NO WAY!**

Comment: Why would you want to select multiple divs when there's only ever one .vis? this just needlessly complicates the logic.

Comment: @KevinB I don't see any HTML element with that class in the OPs question. My answer answers his larger question, while using general code.